# What are the succeed, fail, and done Context Methods For?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

In Node.js, Amazon Lambda functions have a signature that looks like this

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda July 20!'),
    };
    return response
};
```

The `event` parameter contains information about the AWS Service Event that triggered the Lambda.  The `context` parameter contains information about the Lambda environment itself.

The context object [is documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html).  Per those docs, it has a single method named `getRemainingTimeInMillis` and a number of properties.

However, if I log this object, I see the following

```
INFO    {
  callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter],
  succeed: [Function (anonymous)],
  fail: [Function (anonymous)],
  done: [Function (anonymous)],
  functionVersion: '$LATEST',
  functionName: 'july-2021-delete-after-july-31',
  memoryLimitInMB: '128',
  logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/july-2021-delete-after-july-31',
  logStreamName: '2021/07/15/[$LATEST]e05ac24e44d6489b9f8124791b3d5513',
  clientContext: undefined,
  identity: undefined,
  invokedFunctionArn: '...',
  awsRequestId: '7852dc1a-8283-46a1-b445-e6d6187553b6',
  getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function: getRemainingTimeInMillis]
}
```

That is, there's three additional methods named `succeed`, `fail`, and `done`.

```
succeed: [Function (anonymous)],
fail: [Function (anonymous)],
done: [Function (anonymous)],
```

What are these methods for, exactly?  I can take some guesses and Googling around leads to some circumstantial evidence that they're deprecated methods,  but I can't seem to find any documentation on what they're meant to do or how they work.

Comment: I believe those are legacy. They certainly aren't used if you are using an `async` function.

Comment: Useful Jason, thank you. I agree.  They don't seem to be needed if you're using an async function OR using an error-first callback in a non-async function.  Yet, they exist :) Do you happen to know if Amazon mentions them as legacy or deprecated anywhere? (the larger context is I'm working on third party tooling for lambda functions and trying to decide/justify whether we should/shouldn't support these)